# Sensible approach to callbacks on object prototype methods in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures, prototypal-inheritance

Is what I've done below a sensible approach to allow callbacks to run on functions defined in an object's prototype, such that the scope is correct?

I've been wrestling with the correct way to set the value of `this` when an object's prototype method is the one to run in response to a callback which might originate from an AJAX request or from a click binding or whatever.

Here is a simplified annotated version:

```
// everything is inside an object which provides the namespace for the app

var namespace = {

// a fairly vanilla object creation routing, which uses the prototype
// approach for defining the functions on the object

newObj : function(params) {
    var MyObj = function(params) {
        this.property = params.property
    };
    MyObj.prototype = namespace.ObjPrototype;
    return new MyObj(params);
},

// the prototype itself, which defines 2 related functions

ObjPrototype : {

    // The first is called to do some form of asynchronous operation
    // In this case it is an ajax call

    doAsync: function (params) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: params.url,
            data: params.data,
            dataType: params.datatype,
            success: namespace.objClosure(this, "asyncSuccess", ["data"]),
        });

        // the final line above is the key here - it asks a function (below)
        // for a closure around "this", which will in turn run the 
        // function "asyncSuccess" (defined next) with the argument "data"
    },

    // This is the actual callback that I want to run.  But we can't
    // pass this.asyncSuccess to the ajax function above, because the
    // scope at execution time is all wrong

    asyncSuccess : function(params) {
        this.property = params.data;
    },
},

// This is the bit I sort of invented, to help me around this problem.
// It returns a function which provides a closure around the object
// and when that returned function is run it inspects the requested
// arguments, and maps them to the values in the JS default
// "arguments" variable to build a parameters object which is then
// passed to the function on the object

objClosure : function(obj, fn, args) {
    return function() {
        if (args) {
            var params = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                params[args[i]] = arguments[i];
            }
            obj[fn](params);
        } else {
            obj[fn]();
        }

    }
}

}
```

Now, obviously the actual target callback `MyObj.asyncSuccess` needs to know that it's going to get a params object, and what structure it will be, and that knowledge has to be shared by the invoking function `MyObj.doAsync`, but otherwise this seems to work well.

My question is - am I totally mad?  Have I missed something obvious that would solve this problem for me in a simpler/less convoluted way?  Am I just too far down the rabbit hole by this stage?

I've read around a lot of questions on SO and they have all addressed part of my question, but I don't seem to have got to the bottom of a generally accepted solution for this.  I can't be the only person who's ever wanted to do this :)

**Edit**

I've accepted the answer below, but you need to read all the comments too for it to come together.  Thanks folks for your help!

Comment: You should have a look at Function.bind. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: This looks useful, thanks.  I may have to dig deeper into the docs, but I'm not sure how to get bind() to take an arbitrary number of arguments.  If you do fn.bind(obj, arguments), the function receives a single argument containing the JS default "arguments" object, rather than it being unpacked into however many actual arguments the function is expecting.  If that makes sense.  So you can't use it on a function with a sig like `fn(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

Comment: Whenever you want to get rid of the issue of having an Array when you want 'unrolled' arguments for your call, use Function.apply (see mdn). I made a small example here : http://jsbin.com/feyuwogobi/1/   use jsbin or the like to quickly test such issues.

Comment: Magic! That's exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aren't you over complicating things? see if the below code will help you. i did not completely understand your intent but the below code should help you

```
function newObj(params) {
    function asyncSuccess(params) {
        this.property = params.data;
    }

    function objClosure(obj, fn, args) {
        return function() {
            if (args) {
                var params = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    params[args[i]] = arguments[i];
                }
                obj[fn](params);
            } else {
                obj[fn]();
            }

        }
    }
    this.property = params.property
    this.doAsync = function (params) {
    console.log('reached async');
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: params.url,
            data: params.data,
            dataType: params.datatype,
            success: objClosure(this, "asyncSuccess", ["data"]),
        });       
    }    
}
var k = new newObj({'property':'xyz'});
k.doAsync();
```

After seeing the comment from "GameAlchemist" i looked into objClosure function i think we can further improvise by using below code: I am still not sure what the value of this.property or data is to give a proper solution hence just assuming few things

```
function newObj(params) {
    function asyncSuccess(params) {
        this.property = params ? params.data : null;
    }

    function objClosure(args) {
        return function() {
            if (args) {
                var params = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    params[args[i]] = arguments[i];
                }
                asyncSuccess(params);
            } else {
                asyncSuccess();
            }

        }
    }
    this.property = params.property
    this.doAsync = function (params) {
    console.log('reached async');
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: params.url,
            data: params.data,
            dataType: params.datatype,
            success: objClosure(["data"]),
        });       
    }    
}
```

Few issues here:
if you are already passing params.data to data i.e. data:params.data how can you again assign the value this.property = params.data? Few things are confusing but i hope the above solution works : )

Comment: "aren't you over complicating things?" - possibly, that's the crux of my question :)

Comment: They key difference between what I've got and what you've got seems to be in the object construction.  I've gone for a prototype-based approach, and you're defining the functions inside the constructor function, some public some private.  What's interesting for me is that the objClosure bit persists across this change, as that's the bit that I'm mostly questioning.  So, that's encouraging!  I think the style of object construction is not the most important thing here (though I could be wrong) - I think the prototype approach gives me more flexibility for adding other shared functions later.

Comment: Incidentally, I have several objects that may want to use the objClosure, so I'd probably define it outside all of the constructors/prototypes so it is more reusable, but that does increase the complexity of the call to it, as you point out.

Comment: my bad about objClosure, i did not pay enough attention : function objClosure(obj, fn, args) { var _args = args.slice(); _args.unshift(obj);  return Function.bind.apply(fn, _args); }

Comment: @RichardJ Prototype is mainly used for inheritance or if you want to add functionality to an existing object! There is no need for you to use something in prototype just to make it available to all objects. use it within the object itself with public access. The reason why we use prototype with jquery or other objects is the object is already constructed and you want to make other functionality available. If the functionality was inititally designed then jquery would just have a public function and not a function used in prototype

Comment: just do this.objClosure = function () {} and you can use it explicitly!

Comment: @Wishy - yes, sorry, when I said shared, I meant through inheritance - I have a few objects which will need to support the same kinds of operation, so I was going to use the prototype approach to allow me to provide that.  BUT, following on from your comment I've had another look at "JavaScript: The Good Parts", and have understood a bit more about Functional inheritance, so may have a go at that.

Comment: also even if you want few objects which will share same kinds of operations, you can extend this entire object into the prototype of that new object! More simpler i feel!